# how to suppress errors in airflow cli output?

Tags: airflow

Working on some Airflow monitoring ideas.
When I execute `airflow list_tasks my_dag` I get a whole lot of unneeded garbage along with the actual desired output:

```
[2018-12-11 22:39:00,301] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2018-12-11 22:39:00,423] {models.py:271} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2018-12-11 22:39:00,448] {models.py:380} ERROR - Failed to import: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_http_operator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 377, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_http_operator.py", line 27, in <module>
    from airflow.operators.http_operator import SimpleHttpOperator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/http_operator.py", line 21, in <module>
    from airflow.hooks.http_hook import HttpHook
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/http_hook.py", line 23, in <module>
    import tenacity
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 352
    from tenacity.async import AsyncRetrying
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
also_run_this
run_after_loop
run_this_last
runme_0
runme_1
runme_2
```

What I really need out of all this is:

also_run_this

run_after_loop

run_this_last

runme_0

runme_1

runme_2

Is there a way to suppress all, except for the actual result?

Comment: Looks like the master branch of airflow has updated the tenacity dependence to 4.12, which removes this python version incompatibility. The next release (4.10.3?) should probably include the fix.

Comment: TBH I'd seriously like a way to suppress all output when "Filling up the DagBag".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a version of Python that treats `async` as a reserved word. You can either downgrade to a version where that is not the case or you can disable the example DAGs in your configuration.

Comment: These are versions that worked for me:  `python 3.7.0`, `tenacity==5.0.2` and `apache-airflow==1.10.1`.

Comment: Would this also work with `tenacity==5.0.3`, `python 3.7.2` and `apache-airflow==1.10.2`? Generally where can we go to see which libraries are compatible?

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade tenacity to the latest version.
Although during upgrade it shows a warning:
"apache-airflow 1.10.1 has requirement tenacity==4.8.0, but you'll have tenacity 5.0.2 which is incompatible". Please ignore this

Compatibility:
Python 3.7.1
apache-airflow 1.10.1
tenacity 5.0.2

Hope this helps!